# jQuery CookieBar Plugin not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-cookie, timber

I used [CookieBar Plugin](http://www.primebox.co.uk/projects/jquery-cookiebar/) in my Wordpress. Though I include css and js file with initialization for cookiebar, it's not working. Nothing is shown in browser plus no console error.

What am I doing wrong ? Any suggestions/help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a WordPress plugin based on CookieBar Plugin. It works fine. Add some code showing us how you are including css and js. You need to modify js file (no conflict...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the latest Jquery version?

If not here is the CDN to it:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

http://jquery.com/

Comment: then i need some code. It's mpretty difficult to give you an anwser with no code.